# Normalization of cel. files after filtering of non-expressed genes in R

Tags: r, filtering, normalization

Before normalizing my data, I want to perform a filtering where genes that are not expressed are deleted. For this purpose I have specified a threshold value. I would like to do this filtering before normalizing and then normalize it.

```
library(limma)
library(hgu133plus2cdf)
library(affy)
library(dplyr)
library(oligo)

setwd("C:/A549_ALI/4_tert-Butanol (22)/")
data=read.celfiles(list.celfiles())
eset <- rma(data, normalize=FALSE, background=FALSE)

not_expressed_threshold <- quantile(exprs(eset),0.1)
not_expressed <- exprs(eset) < not_expressed_threshold
not_expressed_2 <- rownames(exprs(eset))[not_expressed]
celfiles_filtered <- eset[!rownames(eset) %in% not_expressed_2, ]

cat("Dimensions of celfiles:", dim(eset), "\n")
cat("Dimensions of celfiles_filtered:", dim(celfiles_filtered), "\n")

eset_ <- rma(celfiles_filtered, normalize=FALSE, background=FALSE)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : 
  cannot find inherited method for function 'rma' for signature '"ExpressionSet"'.
```

I tried to filter data directly and then normalize it, but it didn't work either. Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Can you please try and provide a minimal reproducible example?  If your filtering steps are working as expected, then 10 rows of `celfiles_filtered` would probably be sufficient.  (use `dput(head(celfiles_filtered, 10))` and paste into the original question).

Comment: `affy::rma` has a `subset` argument allowing to specify which probes are to be included. So, a strategy could be to identify the "good" subset of probes and then run `rma` on  the cel files again, specifying the subset argument.